# C# can not using **as** to cast base class to derived class

Tags: c#, generics, casting

```
class Building {
}

class Home: Building {
}

private List<Building>   buildings;
public T[] FindBuildings<T>() {       
    return buildings.FindAll(x => x is T).ToArray() as T[];
}
```

I have a list to save all the buildings on the map, and write a function to find the certain building type. 
I want using `FindBuildings<Home>()` to get an array that contains all home buildings on the map, but when I run the code, I found the function always return null, it seems `as` did not work. Does this mean `as` can not using generic type parameter?

So, I change the code:

```
private List<Building>   buildings;
public Building[] FindBuildings<T>() {       
    return buildings.FindAll(x => x is T).ToArray();
}
```

using `FindBuildings<Home>() as Home[]` to access the home buildings on the map. But...it still get null.

I saw a Unity3d's example, show me the using 'as' to convert array type, why I failed?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class example : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnMouseDown() {
        HingeJoint[] hinges = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(HingeJoint)) as HingeJoint[];
        foreach (HingeJoint hinge in hinges) {
            hinge.useSpring = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't cast a `Bulding[]` to a `House[]`, even if you know that each entry of the source array is a `House`.

Comment: For the title: [You can't cast base type object to derived type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124336/a-way-of-casting-a-base-type-to-a-derived-type)

Comment: @Dirk dammit, never mind- I got the cast direction backwards - my bad

Answer (score 10):

You need to do it like this:

```
return buildings.OfType<T>.ToArray();
```

Explanation of why your attempt did not work follows.

The type of the expression `buildings.FindAll(x => x is T)` is `List<Building>`. This is because `buildings` itself is a `List<Building>`, and `FindAll` does not magically change the type of the item in the return value. Therefore, `ToArray()` produces a `Building[]`.

The `as` operator returns a non-null value only in those cases where a straight cast would be valid. Since a cast from `Building[]` to `Home[]` is not valid, `as` always produces `null`. Don't be confused by the fact that casting a `Home[]` to a `Building[]` is valid.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that a `Building[]` isn't a `Home[]`. So this code:

```
public T[] FindBuildings<T>() {       
    return buildings.FindAll(x => x is T).ToArray() as T[];
}
```

... always tries to treat a `Building[]` as a `T[]`, and will return `T[]` when `T` is neither `Building` nor `Object`. You need to create a `T[]` to start with. Fortunately, LINQ actually makes this very easy for you:

```
public T[] FindBuildings<T>() {       
    return buildings.OfType<T>().ToArray();
}
```

This important thing is that [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable<T>` - whereas your call to `List<Building>.FindAll` is still returning a `List<Building>`, so `ToArray` is creating a `Building[]`.

As an aside, I'd thoroughly recommend using casts instead of `as` unless it's *valid* for `as` to return null. If you want a casting failure to be an error condition, a straight cast indicates that via an exception *immediately*, rather than you getting a `NullReferenceException` later on, masking the original problem.